# Change deletion order to delete pointer before variable

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a class with a plain variable, `_apple`, a pointer to a second variable, `_orange`, and a destructor that cleans up `_orange`.

Even though `_orange` is defined *before* `_apple` in my class, it is cleaned up as part of the explicitly defined destructor, and is thus deleted *before* apple, in contrast to the usual "LIFO" deletion order.

In my code, this is an issue, since my "apple" requires "orange" still be alive, and "orange" is mandated to be a pointer because it is virtual and dynamic.

Is there any way to change the deletion order (without any additional overhead)?

MWE:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Food
{
    std::string _name;
    Food(const std::string& name) : _name(name) {}
    ~Food() { std::cout << _name << std::endl; }
};

struct Meal
{
    Food* _orange;
    Food _apple;
    Meal() : _orange(new Food("orange")), _apple("apple") { }
    ~Meal() { delete _orange; }
};

int main()
{
    { Meal meal; }
    return 0;
}
```

```
orange
apple
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You change the deletion order by changing who manages the resource (= allocated memory). If you need pointer semantics, `std::unique_ptr` is a good candidate for this:

```
struct Meal
{
    std::unique_ptr<Food> _orange;
    Food _apple;
    Meal() : _orange(std::make_unique<Food>("orange")), _apple("apple") {}
};
```